# PHP hiding div on empty result from database

Tags: php, html, select, mysqli, hide

I need to hide a full div if variable from database is empty.

I've looked at different similar cases but could not make any of them working. Perhaps someone could help me with it.

So I have my SELECT statement:

```
<?php
$user = 'myuser';
$pass = 'mypassword';
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', $user, $pass );
$sql = "
SELECT id,education_school,education_diploma, DATE_FORMAT(education_start, '%Y %M') as education_start, DATE_FORMAT(education_finish, '%Y %M') as education_finish, education_description
FROM candidates_education
WHERE login='[login]'
ORDER BY education_finish DESC
";
$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
?>
```

And then I have my html (part of it below):

```
<?php foreach ($results as $row) : ?>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:20px;">
<div class="row invoice-cust-add">
<div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:-25px;"   <?php 
if(empty($education_description)||!isset($education_description)) echo 'style="display: none;"'; ?>   >
<p class="invoice-desc" style="line-height:23px; margin-bottom:-30px;"><span class="bold">Addtional description:</span><br/> <?php echo $row['education_description']; ?></p>
</div>                              
</div>  
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The problem I am having is that the div class="col-xs-12" should not be displayed if 'education_description' is empty. What am I doing here wrong?

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: And what is the problem? Except using undefined variable `$education_description`.

Comment: How is your variable `$education_description` being set?

Comment: taking from your both comments, not defined variable $education_description is the problem here

Comment: Is this the answer then?

Comment: it would be the answer, yes. Now all I need to do is set the variable I guess. My php is very very poor :).

Comment: so you want to hide whole div section or just remove `col-xs-12` and you need class replacement if empty? `style="margin-top:-25px` poor choice for boostrap

Comment: You want `$row['education_description']` instead of `$education_description`.

Comment: @skunkhaze I want to hide the whole div when education_description is empty on DB

Comment: @Don'tPanic that does not really work for me

Comment: use `if ($results) { //place foreach and html inside }`

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML code like this:

```
<?php foreach ($results as $row) : 
        $isEmpty = empty($education_description); ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                    <div class="row invoice-cust-add">
                    <div <?php if(!$isEmpty): ?> class="col-xs-12" <?php endif; ?> style="margin-top:-25px;"   <?php 
                        if($isEmpty || !isset($education_description)) echo 'style="display: none;"'; ?>   >
                        <p class="invoice-desc" style="line-height:23px; margin-bottom:-30px;"><span class="bold">Addtional description:</span><br/> <?php echo $row['education_description']; ?></p>
                    </div>                              
                </div>  
            </td>
        </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: aidin - this does not really work as I need. It replaces the class but it still displays the div..

Comment: to see if it would work for me I slighlty modified it: 
    <p class="invoice-desc" style="line-height:23px; margin-bottom:-30px;">
    <span <?php if(!$isEmty): ?> class="bold" <?php endif; ?> <?php if($isEmty || !isset($education_description)) echo 'style="display: none;"'; ?> >Addtional description:</span><br/> 
    <?php echo $row['education_description']; ?></p>

 But it hides the title of the element even if education_description is not empty as per the image ( http://imgur.com/a/50gRe ) - in the second row "Additional Description" should be displayed above "description here"

Answer (score 0):

Don't Panic's solution with

```
$row['education_description']
```

worked after I removed unnecessary part

```
style="margin-top:-25px;"
```

Thank you ALL for help! Your time is much much appreciated